# Validator used to work with TextField and TextArea

Tags: codenameone

I used to add validator constraints on TextFields and TextArea but it now throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addConstraint needs an InputComponent as first argument.

```
    Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new TextModeLayout(3, 2));
    Validator validator = new Validator();
    TextField txt = new TextField();

    validator.addConstraint(txt, new LengthConstraint(1, "HI"));

    Button btnVal = new Button("VALIDATE");
    validator.addSubmitButtons(btnVal);

    hi.add(txt);
    hi.add(btnVal);
    hi.show();
```

Replacing the Textfield with a **TextComponent** works. So is that a regression or is that intended and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a regression due to this PR https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/pull/2475

I've fixed it and we might push a hot fix on Thursday to resolve it.

Comment: Auch. This one hurts. It breaks the development process in a manner which isn't easy to fix. Maybe you should consider making such components interfaces so that a workaround can be easily implemented. Also, I've found that if "isValid" is called for a component for which a constraint has not been added, then a NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace for that exception? Normally these things only happen when we make a mistake which I did when I reviewed the PR poorly. Adding an interface to hide the internal code is a bit problematic. Notice you can compile against the source code as a short term workaround, if more people would have done that we would have discovered the issue before it reached the build servers...

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.codename1.ui.validation.Validator.isValid(Validator.java:647)` it's just trying to call isValid(val) on a null constraint. My guess is that it should simply retrun true if no constraint exist for that component.

Comment: Yes but what's higher in the stack? Who is calling that?

Comment: Just to be sure I committed a patch to workaround a potential issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/59984d04b3dbb8bc96c1e1007b76bad22880c6bb